# using xslt key for finding unique values

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

```
<ROOT>
<AA Aattr="xyz1">
    <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="aaa" >
    </BB>   
    <BB bAttr1="chrome"   bAttr2="aaa" >
    </BB>
    <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="bbb" >
    </BB>
    <BB bAttr1="chrome"   bAttr2="bbb" >
    </BB>
</AA>
<AA Aattr="xyz2">
    <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="aaa" >
    </BB>   
    <BB bAttr1="chrome"   bAttr2="ccc" >
    </BB>
    <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="ddd" >
    </BB>
</AA>
```

I want to select distinct\unique values of attibute 'bAttr2' in node 'BB', from node 'AA' where attribute 'Aattr' is xyz1

say for the given xml, i need to output as "aaa","bbb"

I tried the following logic using key. But didnt worked. Please help

```
<xsl:key name="nameDistinct" match="BB" use="@bAttr1"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="ROOT/AA[@Aattr='xyz1']">
    <xsl:for-each select="BB[generate-id()=generate-id(key('nameDistinct',@bAttr2)[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@bAttr2"/>            
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here:

Filter the items available to the key when you define it:

```
  <xsl:key name="nameDistinct" match="AA[@Aattr = 'xyz1']/BB" use="@bAttr2"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each 
      select="ROOT/AA/BB[generate-id() =
                         generate-id(key('nameDistinct', @bAttr2)[1])]">
      <xsl:value-of select="@bAttr2"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

or filter within the grouping expression:

```
  <xsl:key name="nameDistinct" match="BB" use="@bAttr2"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each 
      select="ROOT/AA/BB[generate-id() =
                         generate-id(key('nameDistinct', @bAttr2)
                                       [../@Aattr = 'xyz1']
                                       [1])]">
      <xsl:value-of select="@bAttr2"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

the former approach is a bit less messy and marginally more efficient, while the latter allows you to parameterize the grouping (i.e. group on values that aren't hardcoded as 'xyz1'), e.g.:

```
  <xsl:key name="nameDistinct" match="BB" use="@bAttr2"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/AA">
      <xsl:for-each
        select="BB[generate-id() =
                   generate-id(key('nameDistinct', @bAttr2)
                                    [../@Aattr = current()/@Aattr]
                                    [1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@bAttr2"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
 <xsl:key name="kCompoundAttribs" match="BB"
  use="concat(generate-id(..), '+', @bAttr2)"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/*[1]/*
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kCompoundAttribs',
                      concat(generate-id(..),'+', @bAttr2)
                      )[1]
                  )
     ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ROOT>
    <AA Aattr="xyz1">
        <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="aaa" ></BB>
        <BB bAttr1="chrome"   bAttr2="aaa" ></BB>
        <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="bbb" ></BB>
        <BB bAttr1="chrome"   bAttr2="bbb" ></BB>
    </AA>
    <AA Aattr="xyz2">
        <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="aaa" ></BB>
        <BB bAttr1="chrome"   bAttr2="ccc" ></BB>
        <BB bAttr1="firefox"  bAttr2="ddd" ></BB>
    </AA>
</ROOT>
```

**produces two `BB` elements, whose `bAttr2` attributes have the desired set of distinct values** (if you want just the string values of the attributes, just use `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each` for that expression):

```
<BB bAttr1="firefox" bAttr2="aaa"/>
<BB bAttr1="firefox" bAttr2="bbb"/>
```

**Do note**:

This solution is simpler and more easier to understand and more efficient than "filtering" :)

Comment: @adrian-w Please, note that "`xml`" is the default value for the `@method` attribute of the `<xsl:output>` declaration. This means that we don't have to specify the `@method` attribute at all, if it is "xml"

Comment: Hmm, not as easy as that. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/REC-xslt20-20210330/#element-output) says: _The default for the method attribute depends on the contents of the tree being serialized_ (this is the spec 2.0, but in 1.x it is the same). But indeed in this case it should be xml. However, when I run this in Altova XMLSpy, it outputs HTML if I don't specify a method. May be a bug in XMLSpy. Anyway IMHO I would recommend adding the output method to be compatible with all environments.

Comment: @AdrianW I strongly recommend contacting Altova. Maybe you are not using their latest version in which this issue might have been fixed, or otherwise they need to be made aware of this. Your issue has been the only one of this type that have been raised to my attention in the last 20 years.

Comment: @AdrianW, the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/REC-xslt20-20210330/#element-output)  states (2nd bullet)  that the only case when the default value is set to "html" is: "If the expanded-QName of this first element child has local part html (in any combination of upper and lower case) and a null namespace URI, then the default output method is html". If this is not your case, then this is clearly a bug in XML Spy. Please, do note that the transformation on the provided XML document in this answer clearly does not satisfy the condition in the bullet, thus the output method will be "xml"

Comment: Using latest XMLSpy 2023. So, that's not the problem. I have now seen that they have a setting in the program's options labelled _Default file extension_, which is set to `.html` by factory default (at least, I cannot remember ever having touched this). That implicitly determines the default for the output method. So, one can make XMLSpy standard compliant by setting the default extension to `.xml`.

Comment: @AdrianW +++  1000000  :)